# Check if current user is NOT administrator in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I really need some simply help. All I want is:

```
if user=admin
   do this
elseif user != admin
   do that
else
   do something else
```

Now I have found the answer to check whether the user is admin, but do not know how to check if he is NOT admin. Hope you can help.

Thanks :)

#### EDIT:

Thanks for the answers, but here is what I am really trying to achieve:

On the top of my site, I have a header (like here on StackOverflow, the black header). If user is not logged in, it simply says "Hello, Guest." Now, I have a plugin that redirects users to the homepage after logging in (instead of going to the dashboard). In the header it says now "Hello, $username".

But when I login as admin, I want the "Hello, $username" to have a hyperlink linking to wp-admin. All other users that login should have NO link.

That's why I need not only check whether user is admin, but also if he/she is not admin.

Hope my question got a bit clearer. As always, thanks in advance :)

Comment: start from here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131814/if-current-user-is-admin-or-editor

Comment: This could be useful: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

You can check his capabilites.

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    // user has admin rights
} else {
    // no admin rights
}
```

Note that `is_admin` does not tell you if its an admin, it just checks if admin side code is being run ( which could be via ajax, and therefore not necessarily an admin doing it ).

Answer (score 0):

```
Check url http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_super_admin

if ( is_super_admin($user_id) ) {
    echo 'Admin';
}else{
    echo 'Not admin';
}
```